# Why WebService (.Net C#) is responding 404 on HTTPS and responding 400 on HTTP

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis, https

How can I get the Same Response in both HTTPS and HTTP.
I have installed the certificate on IIS.
Service is deployed on IIS.
Main Page gives the same response on HTTP and HTTPS.

My Web Config File Looks like this.

**Web Config File**

```
 <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RestService.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
      
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
        <endpoint address="basic" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="HttpEndPoint" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl"/>
        <endpoint address="Service1.svc" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
       
      <webHttpBinding>
      
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"  closeTimeout="00:10:00"
    openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
    sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
    
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="TransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" minFreeMemoryPercentageToActivateService="0" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

[On Https Error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJXMH.png)
[On Http Error 400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOc8W.png)

Comment: The URL needs to be HTTP when not using a certificate and HTTPS when using certificate.  Make sure a service is running for the URL you are using.  If HTTPS (uses TLS for authentication), you will not get any response if the TLS fails.  So either you are going to a site that doesn't support HTTPS or the URL doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is because https://localhost/webService/RestServiceImpl.svc/basic does not exist. If HTTPS is used, no response will be received when TLS fails. If you access
https://localhost/webService/RestServiceImpl.svc/basic/test, you will also get a 404 error.

**One more thing to note is that we cannot access the address of the endpoint. All the endpoint information is contained in the WSDL file of the service base address. We can only access the service base address. All you should visit https://localhost/webService/RestServiceImpl.svc.**